# git gui blame causes 'CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed an URL which has no schema' errors

Tags: git, macos, git-gui, tcltk

This is on latest OSX with the latest version of git.

The issue is that when you do 'git gui blame', a highly annoying list of errors fills your terminal window, to wit:

> CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed an URL which has no schema
>
> CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed an URL which has no schema
>
> CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed an URL which has no schema
>
> CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed an URL which has no schema

I looked around and saw other posts talking about this, none of which talked about how to fix 'git gui blame'. The post about gitk was the closest.

I tried 'brew install tcl-tk', but that doesn't fix the issue. I also upgraded to the latest git.

I then poked around how git gui blame is implemented, and eventually discovered that it ultimately executes this script:

> /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.19.2/share/git-gui

which contains

`#!/bin/sh
if test "z$*" = zversion ||
   test "z$*" = z--version
then
    echo 'git-gui version 0.21.GITGUI'
else
    libdir="${GIT_GUI_LIB_DIR:-/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.19.2/share/git-gui/lib}"
    exec "$libdir/Git Gui.app/Contents/MacOS/Wish" "$0" "$@"
fi`

The 'Wish' here is an OSX application which uses the built-in version of tcl-tk. Which I guess explains why installing a new version of tck-tk doesn't affect it, since it's got a hardcoded path to the built-in (old) version of tcl-tk in it.

I'm able to hide the error messages by changing /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.19.2/share/git-gui like this:

`#!/bin/sh
if test "z$*" = zversion ||
   test "z$*" = z--version
then
    echo 'git-gui version 0.21.GITGUI'
else
    libdir="${GIT_GUI_LIB_DIR:-/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.19.2/share/git-gui/lib}"
    exec "$libdir/Git Gui.app/Contents/MacOS/Wish" "$0" "$@" 2>/dev/null
fi`

Note the redirect '2>/dev/null'.

However I feel like this isn't really a brillant fix, it's only hiding the error. Plus, it'll revert when I upgrade git.

Does anyone have any idea of how to really fix the problem?

Comment: Did you report it here: https://git-scm.com/community??